# How to clean a ceiling fan with retractable fan blades?

Tags: cleaning, ceiling-fan

I bought a few ceiling fans with retractable fan blades. After using for a few months, there is a thick layer of dusk underneath the blades at the kink. I saw a [video](https://youtu.be/OhiAQ2n5-RM) suggesting two persons to do the job. One to extend the blades and hold on to it while the other wiping it down with a damp cloth. Is there an easier way the get the job done with just one person only and without dismantling the fan?

Comment: Hi! It looks like you have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple of spring loaded clamps to hold the fan blades out while you wipe them down. Just be careful that they don’t apply so much force that they break the plastic.

[A manual can be found here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1014019/Fanaway-Evo2.html?page=9#manual). Unfortunately it only suggests a soft brush and no water. Nothing about extending the blades.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you go through the instruction manual and look for information on how to clean the specific device. If you don't find any, go back to the store where you bought it from and ask the personnel there. On the other hand, you can ask for a friend's help and clean your fan the way the video suggests instead of wasting time to do the prior.